# Saving POJO with ArrayList member in Postgres database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, ibatis

I have a Pojo definition like this:

```
Public class MyPojo
{
  String id;
  ArrayList<String> entries;
}
```

I have a Postgres DB table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE(
ID SERIAL,
ENTRIES VARCHAR ARRAY,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

I am trying to use Ibatis' `com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient` interface's update function

```
SQLmap.update("writeDB", obj);
```

The query is:

```
insert into MYTABLE(ENTRIES)
values
(#entries#)
```

However, I get an invalid query exception with the following message:

> *** Exception: 
>   --- The error occurred in XXXXXSQLMap.xml. 
>   --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map. 
>   --- Check the XXXXX.insertYYYYY-InlineParameterMap. 
>   --- Check the parameter mapping for the 'entries' property. 
>   --- Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException ***

What's the cause of this error?
How do I store the arraylist in my POJO in database?

Comment: What is the "invalid query error"?

Comment: Isnt this a basic iBatis configuration issue that is probably explained in the documentation? (cue *collection*)

Comment: I am sorry, I am totally new to IBATIS, Spring etc. Can you please ellaborate/provide pointers?

Comment: The exception I see is the one below:

*** Exception:   
--- The error occurred in XXXXXSQLMap.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the XXXXX.insertYYYYY-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the parameter mapping for the 'zzzz' property.  
--- Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException ***

Comment: Are you sure the entries member variable is not null?  The NPE leads me to believe you are trying to save an instance where the ArrayList is null

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this seems to be some problem with Mapper xml file. Can you post your Mapper xml code? Meanwhile this may help you http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html